# Nginx HTTPS 301 redirect to another TLD (hosted on same server) without showing SSL warning

Tags: redirect, ssl, nginx, https, tld

I own the domains

```
     example.com,  .com.au,  .net,  .net.au, ...  (8 in total).
```

I want all of these TLD's to 301 redirect to the secure *.com* domain

> ```
>     https://www.example.com
> ```

I have it working using Nginx for all HTTP requests but not all *HTTPS*.

I have installed a SSL certificate for `https://www.example.com` and this works for *www* and *non-www* without any security warnings (as expected).

When browsing to say `http://example.net`  I get redirected to `https://www.example.com` without security warnings. However, when browsing to `https://example.net` I get the dreaded security warning.

Now I assume this is due to me only owning the *.com* SSL certificate and not for the *other* TLDs. Also, all sites are hosted on the *same* server/ip address, thus the *.com* certificate being returned for other TLDs.

DNS A records for all domains point to the single IP address of my Nginx server.

From what I have read and understood, I think I need an IP address and SSL certificate for each TLD I own. This seems like overkill for a simple redirect.

Is there any Nginx or DNS trickery I can use to avoid the standard security warnings for the *OTHER* (non .com TLD's) 
without having to fork out for more IP addresses and SSL certificates?

I thought I better ask the brains trust before I go ahead and purchase all the required certs etc.

Below is my Nginx config:

```
server {                  # redirect/catch all block
        listen 80;
        listen 443;
        server_name _ .example.com .example.com.au .example.net .example.net.au;
        return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
        listen   443 ssl default_server;        # Secure default server block
        server_name www.example.com;

        root /srv/www/example.com/public_html;
        index index.html index.htm;

        ssl on;
        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/server.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/server.key;           
        # ...   rest of config
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> From what I have read and understood, I think I need an IP address and SSL certificate for each TLD I own. This seems like overkill for a simple redirect.

The redirect is done at the HTTP layer. But in HTTPS the HTTP layer is encapsulated inside TLS. This means it must first successfully establish the TLS connection before it can do the redirect. Thus it needs a proper certificate for all the hostnames you access through HTTPS, even if you just do a redirect to another host.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation! Does the protocol (and Nginx) allow for multiple https domains on the same server (and IP address) assuming I have a certificate from a CA for each domain? Or do I need to have a separate IP address for each secure domain? i.e. how do shared hosting providers handle this?

Comment: To rephrase my question: Is the hostname also encapsulated when establishing the TLS connection or does nginx have access to it? If the hostname is also encapsulated then I guess it relies on IP address (from DNS records) and I will need separate IP's for each domain.

Comment: With Server Name Indication (SNI) you can have multiple certficates behind the same IP. nginx supports that and all modern browsers too, but older browsers like IE8 do not support it. An alternative would be to get a single certificate which includes all necessary names.

Comment: Follow up: I ended up going the single certificate route. I purchased a Comodo PositiveSSL Multi-domain certificate from [namecheap](https://www.namecheap.com/security/ssl-certificates/comodo/positivessl-multi-domain.aspx) with 16 SANS (8 www & 8 without www) for under $200. No extra IP addresses to buy, and now I only have one certificate to administrate on one IP address. Thanks heaps!

Answer (score 1):

I was able to successfully accomplish something very similar by setting the first redirecting server as default. Then the 2nd more-specific server handles all the traffic. Note the change to `default_server` and `server_name`. My certificate isn't assigned to IP addresses, only domain names, and the redirection occurs without an error in Chrome, but in Safari it pops up a warning in my tests visiting `https://<the-ip>`.

```
server {
# default for all, except other more-specific blocks
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen 443 ssl default_server;
        server_name _;

        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/server.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/server.key;

        return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
        listen   443 ssl;
        server_name www.example.com;

        root /srv/www/example.com/public_html;
        index index.html index.htm;

        ssl on;
        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/server.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/server.key;           
        # ...   rest of config
}
```