# Redirect to new domain using https Apache

Tags: apache, .htaccess, dns

I've got this domain:

www.example.com

And I want to redirect it to

https://www.example2.com

This is what I have in my .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On


    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$
    RewriteRule (.*)$ https://www.example2.com/$1 [R=301,L]


    #Joomla Rules


     RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
     RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

If I try from www.example.com the rules are applied it and redirects me, but when I try from example.com it shows me an insecurity error (NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID). How can I make it work both ways?

P.S. both domains point to the same IP

Comment: you don't need mod_rewrite for any of it. just `RedirectPermanent / http://example2.com` in the https and http definitions of the site.

Comment: I found this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25196891/nginx-https-301-redirect-to-another-tld-hosted-on-same-server-without-showing and I think that was the real problem, because when I issued an SSL with let's encrypt, everything worked, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check the below code for redirect one domain to another domain :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [OR]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$
  RewriteRule (.*)$ http://www.example2.com/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

OR

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example2.com/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

I hope it's helpful to you.

Comment: Thank you, but as I posted in the previous comment, my problem was that i needed to have a valid SSL certificate for the redirected domain as well.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I cannot just redirect to an SSL domain if the redirected domain isn't SSL as well, this post gave me the answer.

[Nginx HTTPS 301 redirect to another TLD (hosted on same server) without showing SSL warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25196891/nginx-https-301-redirect-to-another-tld-hosted-on-same-server-without-showing)

Thank you!